# How to add more than one space between particular pieces of words?

Tags: html, css

Just wondering if there's a neat way of doing this using html and css only.

I want to display 3 lines, each includes a name and a phone number and it should look something like this:

one name, multiple spaces followed by a phone number. Then a new line starting with one name and multiple spaces followed by another phone number and the same logic goes for the 3rd line.

The purpose of multiple spaces is for indentation so that the names and phone numbers would look nice on a webpage.

I think it's ugly to insert multiple &nbsp there(unless there're no other options)...

Any neat and clever ways to do it?

Thanks a lot!
(btw I'm using 3 paragraphs at the moment for the above.)

Comment: There are a million ways of doing this. This is too broad a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can use span with col layout and style accordingly

Comment: Use CSS Pseudo Selector ::before or ::after, then you can finetune exactly the space you want using only CSS

Comment: This site is not meant to ask people to write your code for you, so ... do you have anything up until this point? How far did you get? Can you show the existing source (with the non-breaking spaces)? If you can't, I'll bet this question will be closed soon

Comment: The question itself is relatively limited (though too abstract, with no code); the question *title* is misleading and look far too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W7wXa/2/

markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div>Name 1</div>
        <div>Name 2</div>
        <div>Name 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div>123-456-7890</div>
        <div>123-456-7890</div>
        <div>123-456-7890</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.left {
    display: inline-block;
}

.right {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want a table.

If not, you probably want a list, with some items (phone numbers) set to `float: right`, or to `display: inline-block`, with some left margin.

Answer (score 1):

use a span class for phone number with **margin-left:10px** .and can change margin-left position with pixel value you need in b/w name and phone number.see the code below

html

```
Name<span class="phone">1234567890</span></br>
Name<span class="phone">1234567890</span></br>
Name<span class="phone">1234567890</span></br>
```

css

```
.phone
{
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is a viable solution as well. That being said, I'm under the impression that <span> and </br> are not "pure" in css3 and that's why I prefer the solution provided by link13. Please correct me if I'm under the wrong impression, thanks.

Comment: ya that's a genuine solution and here i just put this code to simplify your needs in otherwise too.thanks for your feedback..

Answer (score 0):

If indentation is the issue, you can use a table. You can align the cells within a table to get your desired output.